# How to retrieve entities from datastore in reverse store order using objectify?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class ActionIndex extends EntityObjectAutoID {

    @Parent Ref<Action> action;
    @Id Long id;
    @Index List<Long> receivers;
....
}
```

I want to retrieve the keys of the latest 10 entities that were added to datastore. But if I use this query:

```
ofy().load().type(ActionIndex.class).limit(10).keys().list();
```

of course I get the first 10 entities instead of the last 10. According to [Objectify's doc](http://docs.objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/git/apidocs/com/googlecode/objectify/cmd/Query.html#order%28java.lang.String%29):

> You can sort on @Id properties if this query is restricted to a Class
>   which has no @Parent. Note that this is only important for descending
>   sorting; default iteration is key-ascending.
>
> You can not sort on @Parent properties.

Since my class has a parent (and I need it to have it), what can I do to get the entities in reverse added order without having to add an extra timestamp property?

Comment: Try adding a Date property in each entity where you can store the time of insert. Than order by that property

Comment: yup, that is a viable solution but I wonder if I could get the keys sorted somehow without having to add an extra property. Maybe it is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it. In order to sort by key, you just need to use `__key__` as property. For filtering there is a convenience method called filterKey, but its equivalent for sorting (orderKey), as far as I can see, does not exist.

`ofy().load().type(ActionIndex.class).order("-__key__").limit(10).keys().list();`

--- Edit ----

Based on the comments below, it appears the use of a Date property is compulsory.

Comment: Note that this does not guarantee that you get the right ordering - with scattered id allocation, ids may be wildly different. Even with the old id allocator, they are allocated in chunks and not necessarily monotonic.

Comment: @stickfigure Thanks for the note. It is a question certainly beyond my level of understanding.So, must I use a Date property to guarantee right ordering? Is that the only solution?

Comment: That's the right idea, but keep in mind that even Date does not guarantee exact ordering because clocks may skew on multiple instances. Creating a distributed, monotonically increasing value is hard. However, if you can accept a little slop in this, an indexed Date should work as long as you don't have more than a few hundred writes per second (read about table splitting).

Comment: Your solution would be a good enough approximation for me (it would work on the Kinds where I assign increasing id's), but it fails due to no index.  I find this odd - why would the key/id field need an index?